# Overriding setTransform for UIView breaks drawing on the UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a view (it's the view that is zoomed in a scrollview) that I am trying to make only stretch in the x direction when the user pinches or double-taps to zoom. This view is being constantly drawn on: up to 10 times per second, using Core Graphics to draw a graph.

So I override setTransform like so:

```
- (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)newValue;
{
    CGAffineTransform constrainedTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    constrainedTransform.a = newValue.a;
    [super setTransform:constrainedTransform];
}
```

And this generally gives me the behavior I want, except for one big problem. When the view is being drawn on very often and the user double taps to zoom in, the whole view will often just go black. This happens very rarely if I don't override the above method (although it still does happen once in a while). Also interesting is that when the user zooms using a pinch gesture, this does not happen. This is the function triggered by the double tap:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    CGRect frame = [[self tiledScrollView] frame];
    float newScale = [[self tiledScrollView] zoomScale] * kZoomStep;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForFrame:frame withScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView]]];
    [[self tiledScrollView] zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}
```

And the pinch gestures are just handled by UIScrollView's stock pinch recognizer. One thing that does bother me about the above function is that zoomRect is scaled in both the x and y directions even though my view only scales in one direction. I have tried scaling zoomRect in only the x direction and then calling zoomToRect, but then the graph won't zoom.

So it seems that UIScrollView's pinch recognizer and my double tap recognizer scale the view in two different ways, and only the pinch recognizer's way works with my code... Also, this problem becomes very rare when the drawing rate is slowed, and nonexistent when there is no drawing going on. I've tried using queues to make drawing and zooming sequential but I haven't had much luck with that. I suspect that zoomToRect and other zooming methods may dispatch tasks off to other threads or whatever so I don't think they can be sequentialized that way. But is this something I should look into more?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've wasted days trying to fix this already -_- Thanks